# When I zoom my mapView to show my annotations, the selected annotations are partially off screen

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When I execute the following code snippet, the map zooms correctly to encompass all annotations, however the callouts are partially offscreen. What is the most elegant way of fixing that?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didAddAnnotationViews views: [AnyObject]!) {
// once annotationView is added to the map, get the last one added unless it is the user's location:
  if let annotationView = views.last as? MKAnnotationView where !(annotationView.annotation is MKUserLocation) {
  // show callout programmatically:
  mapView.selectAnnotation(annotationView.annotation, animated: false)
  // zoom to all annotations on the map:
  mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then I had the same issue. I'm not sure if this is the most "elegant" solution, but a simple delay did the trick for me. You could try something similar, like this:

```
    //Assuming this is how you center
    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)

    //Delaying the showing of annotation because otherwise the popover appears at "old" location before zoom finishes
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(0.75 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotationView.annotation, animated: false)
    }
```

Note that I used an arbitrary time of 0.75 seconds; this may be more or less than what you need - if you really want (I was lazy), you could make that number dependent on the distance you have to zoom in; or, be extra clever and find out how to get the zoom in time.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. I eventually went for a custom function with UIEdgeInsets. I guess either approach is a bit of a clutch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, I tried @Jona approach of a delay, but I found that on certain devices it works and others it doesn't. Its all down to the device setup/performance, so using delays isn't really the best solution.

My problem was that I was trying to move/zoom the map (with animation) before opening the callout view (with animation) on the specific pin I wanted to show. Doing this lead to poor performance and the callout being partially off screen.

I decided to use the `UIView animateWithDuration` method, this method has its own completion block and thus no delay is needed. Note: when using the `UIView animateWithDuration` method, you can set the `animated` method to `NO` (or `false` in Swift). As the `UIView` animation block will take care of the animation for us.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

    // Loop through the pins on the
    // map and find the added pin.

    for (MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {

        // If the current pin is the
        // added pin zoom in on it.

        if (annotationView.annotation != mapView.userLocation) {

            // Set the map region to be
            // close to the added pin.
            MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.15, 0.15);
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotationView.annotation.coordinate, span);
            [mapView regionThatFits:region];

            // Only perform the annotation popup
            // when the animation has been completed.
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) animations:^{

                // Set the map region.
                [mapView setRegion:region];

             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 // Force open the annotation popup.
                 [usersMap selectAnnotation:annotationView.annotation animated:YES];
             }];
        }
    }
}
```